# google maps v3 api codeigniter library

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps

please i need assistance on this error that shows error :This webpage is not allowed to request directions on localhost or webhost

Controller:

```
$this->load->library('googlemaps');
```

$this->load->library('googlemaps');
    $config['center'] = 'udaipur, rajasthan, india';

```
$config['zoom'] = 'auto';

$config['directions'] = TRUE;

$config['directionsMode'] = "WALKING";

$config['directionsStart'] = 'auto';

$config['directionsEnd'] = '24.6045763,73.6853708';

$config['directionsDivID'] = 'directionsDiv';

$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

view:

```
<?php echo $map['html']; ?>

<?php echo $map['js']; ?>
<?php echo $map['html']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution i just had to enable direction api and thanks to whoever gave negative vote to this post